# mongoDB Shell Returning products who are 5% far from the minimum stock

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongodb-query, mongodb-shell

**I try to Return all the products who are 5% far from the minimum stock in mongoDB**

in the mongoDB product collation I have :

`_id, name, img, price, inStock`

```
_id: ObjectId("6523432dfsad123323g6h")
name: air force
img: "some URL"
price: 250 
inStock: 60
```

minimum stock is 0

And if that helps, let's say the maximum stock is 50

Imagine I have more such products like this And I want to return only the products that are going to run out

I tried a lot of ways but I can not if anyone can help me I would be very happy I try to do this only in mongodb shell. ty

Comment: If `inStock` is how many are currently in stock, how is minimum stock expressed? You cannot query what is not represented in the dataset.

Comment: I will add that inStock it value and not array. For example it is inStock : 50
better example 

_id:ObjectId("6523432dfsad123323g6h")

name: air force

img:"some URL"

price: 250

inStock: 50

Comment: Is "minimum stock" 0 for every item? .. 10? ... 20?

Comment: @rickhg12hs minimum stock is  0

Comment: What is "5% far from" 0?

Comment: @rickhg12hs ok lets say minimum is 10.
My intention is I want to return all the products that are about to run out

Comment: 5% far from 10 is 10.5.  So, rounding up, you want to check if `"inStock"` is less than, or equal to 11?

Comment: @rickhg12hs yes how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to find docs where `"inStock"` is `"$lte"` to 11.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "inStock": {
    "$lte": 11
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vNoKXNWRAg1).